# how center my react-native svg in my view and all my screens

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg

,

I would like to center an svg ellipse in va vue in order to make a rounded halfway down my screen. I can get the ellipse in question but I can't center my svg......

[image: my screen]

my svg component : 
    const SvgComponent = props => (

```
<Svg
    height="50%"
    width="100%"
>
    <Ellipse
        cx="185"
        cy="145"
        rx="200"
        ry="130"
        stroke="black"
        strokeWidth="2"
        fill="white"
     />
</Svg>
)
```

and my view:

```
  <View style={{backgroundColor: '#3C4550', flex:1, height:'100%', width:'100%', justifyContent: 'center', }} >
      <View style={{ height: '50%' , width: '100%', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' ,backgroundColor: '#FFF'}}>
        <Image style={{height: '40%', width:'45%', backgroundColor:'grey', borderRadius: 80 }}/>
      </View>  
      <SvgComponent />
  </View>
```

I tried a lot of things, even with a simple view but I can't get the expected result, having my screen split in two with the bottom of the rounded top part

An idea ?

Comment: have you tried to set equal width and height for the svg element?

Comment: @jetblack Yes, I tried, but no, it doesn't work.